# NGINX Clean URL ReWrites. How?

Tags: nginx, regex

I have spent several hours trying to figure out in NGINX **what is otherwise and incredibly trivial task in Apache**.

I am exhausted...

I have installed NGINX right out of the box.

`html` is the **root** folder.

I

**JSON Internal Interface**

```
html
html/api
html/api/v1
html/api/v1/getUsers.php
```

**HTML External Interface**

```
html
html/gui
html/gui/v1
html/gui/v1/get/users/1001
```

I have a working location block which illustrates the final goal.

```
location = /get/users/1001 {

  add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  return 200 'This non physical URL path needs to point to html/api/v1/getUsers.php?userId=1001';

}
```

How can a person accomplish this. I am seriously about to go back to Apache and never look back.

**Here is a sample of how I perfectly accomplish this task in Apache** by placing the following Apache directives inside an .htaccess file located in `html/gui/v1`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^get/users/(\d+)/?$ getUser.php?userId=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nginx** [rewrite](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) directive works almost identically as `RewriteRule` in Apache2. So all you need is:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/get/users/(\d+)/?$ /getUsers.php?userId=$1 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    # PHP-FPM config
}
```

or, if you prefer [named captures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13706658/11748454):

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/get/users/(?<userId>\d+)/?$ /getUsers.php?userId=$userId last;
}
```

All URI paths are absolute.

Since you are mentioning regexp locations in your title, your example can be generalized to:

```
location ~ ^/get/users/(\d+)/?$ {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 /getUsers.php?userId=$1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I have added `/?` at the end of `(\d+)` in case of the presence or absence of a trailing slash at the end. Now both match.